# how do I reset netmon using powershell?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, powershell, netmon

Im using powershell, as Administrator in windows8.1.
I give the command `Restart-Service netmon` but it fails with no service found.
ok, how do I restart netmon then?

Comment: The reason it isn't work is because your syntax isn't correct.  [Restart-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849823.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  You should have used `Restart-Service -Name netmon` instead.  You will need to be sure you use the name of an actual service that exists, your syntax as provide in your question, is incorrect though.

Comment: "Netmon" is not a standard Windows 8.1 service, so this is something you've added (or a typo?).  So, is their actually a "Netmon" service on that computer?  If you run `sc query netmon` from a command prompt, does it report that a service with that name is installed?

Comment: @Ramhound the "-name" qualifier is unneeded when there are no ambiguous arguments. MS's basic instructions for using the command  say "To use Restart-Service simply call the cmdlet followed by the service name: `Restart-Service btwdins`"

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Every example in the documention on the cmdlet uses the `-Name` qualifier though

Comment: It is worth pointing out that `netmon` or  [Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) does not even appear to be a service but an executable.

Comment: @Ramhound Looking at TechNet for powershell 1.0: ["Using the Restart-Service Cmdlet"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176942.aspx), three's no mention of it.  Looking at TechNet for PS v5: ["Restart-Service"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849823.aspx) lists the "default parameters" showing the `-Name` qualifier as optional (it's in square brackets in the docs).  My point is tho is simply that the OPs syntax is correct. :)   I think we're on the same page tho -- the OP is just referencing an invalid service, as the error message told him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - your Service Same doesn't always match the Service Display Name.  In this example - I would need to `Restart-Service vds`:

[image]

If you want to get a full service list and look at the service name, you can do a simple `Get-Service`:
[image]

You could then narrow this down using a "Where" clause similar to this `Get-Service | Where {$_.Name -like "Net*"}`:
[image]

(Or you could just find your service in `services.msc` or you could use `sc query`)

When you have your actual service name, you can then restart, stop, start or query the service:
[image]
[Stop-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849790.aspx) | [Start-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849825.aspx) | [Restart-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849823.aspx) | [Get-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849804.aspx)

Sometimes you will get a service error stating that the service isnt installed on your machine.  Normally this is because you aren't running "As Admistrator":
[image]

By Elevating, these commands will start to work again:
[image]
The error message isn't very good for this - and I've seen it trip people up before several times.

Edit - just re-read your question and seen you say you are running as Admin already.  Are you able to post a screenshot for us please?  Or confirm it by running the following:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)){
Write-Warning “You do not have Administrator rights to run this script!`nPlease re-run this script as an Administrator!”
}
```

If your session has been properly elevated, you won't get the warning as shown in the below screenshot:
[image]